# Getting Raise TypeError: Expected a string value in python jwt

Tags: python, jwt

Not been able to generate token because of this error

```py
if check_password_hash(user.password, auth.password):
        token = jwt.encode({'public_id':user.public_id,'exp':
        datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)},app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        print(token)

        return jsonify({'token':token.decode("UTF-8")})
```

Comment: Check if user object is actuallly getting in, check if SECRET_KEY is defined. Also remove the print(token) before the return everything else looks good.

Comment: Which line is triggering the TypeError?

Comment: I don't know, After passing name and password in  basic authentication. token=jwt is giving error

Comment: Yes @EddwinPaz SECRET_KEY is defined. After removing print(token) error is same. I cant find why it is asking for string value.

Comment: what library are you using for jwt?

Comment: @EddwinPaz I have installed PyJWT

Answer (score 3):

You should add

```
JWT_SECRET_KEY="some_random_string"
```

in settings.py file and it will run fine